# Weird symbol in my excel data

Tags: sql-server, excel

I've the following problem, I have an Excel with three rows, I've copied the thrid row of these in the seventh column (as you can see in the first image) to do a query in SQL Server, apparently the data is clean (as you can see the second image) but when I copy this query in another text editor (W3Schools in this case, third image) this shows an weird symbol ("hidden" in the Excel and SQL Server editor) than I cannot delete with any SQL function, always it launches an erro; I want to quit this symbol and left my data clean. Thank you so much

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't worry. this must be some special symbol or UNICODE character that SSMS can't display.

Comment: Possible tab, carriage return or line feed characters. Check for ASCII codes 9, 10, 13, using `CHAR(10)`, `CHAR(9)`, `CHAR(13)`.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SQL, but would the source of that issue be SQL, or something in Excel or with the Excel data?

Comment: Please: Do not provide pictures! Or - if needed - place them together with the real data (copy'n'paste). I'd copy this into a hex-editor and look what kind of character it is. How is the value getting into the excel sheet? Best guess has WEI_DBA suggesting some kind of line break or CSV separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had something similar happen to me, and while this solution may not work for you, it's worth a shot.

Go to the cell holding the value of **4013802** and click into it. Press <kbd>Home</kbd> to get to the very far left of the cell. Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd> **once**, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy. It may look like it didn't grab anything, but trust that it did.

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the *Find and Replace* dialog window. In the *Find what:* field, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>; leave the *Replace with:* field blank. Now click **Replace All** and see if it returns anything.

If Excel says it made replacements, try using your Excel data again and see if you get the weird character again. If Excel says it cannot find any data to replace, you may be dealing with something different.

That being said, it's definitely an unidentified character in the character set being used by Excel and SS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all, issue solved!! I just've replaced that character by a white space with a function.